# javascript css @media screen

Tags: javascript, css

How to change style css value using javascript?

If you change the css style using javascript, then the style will be added to the general css style. See image below.
Question: how to add or change style in media screen?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to modify the actual CSS file itself?  Something else?  This sounds like the makings of an XY Problem.  Can you elaborate on what you’re actually trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: There may be some confusion about what element.style.display does in JavaScript. It is changing the style attribute of an element. It is not changing anything in a stylesheet.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you trying to change the display value of a particular element or are you trying to change the value in a stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

Try to give it `!important` to be

```js
el.style.setProperty("display", "block !important")
```

### Solution 2

First, set the display to a variable:

```css
.div2 {
  --display: none;
  display: var(--display);
}
```

```js
el.style.setProperty("--display", "block");
```

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to the --variable, I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the device width.

```
const width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth ||document.body.clientWidth;
(width > 500) ? el.style.setProperty("display", "block !important") : el.style.setProperty("display", "none !important")
```